# Select2 usage in Project. License

Tags: jakarta-ee, licensing, project, jquery-select2

I'm not fluent in english and I'm not sure if I can use select2 library in commercial application. I have a task that would be a lot easier if I could use select2 library, but I'm not shure if I can use it freely.

```
Select2 is licensed under the Apache Software Foundation License Version 2.0 and GPL Version 2.0. Coded by Igor Vaynberg.
```

Can anybody give me an answer?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/197502/can-i-use-select2-in-my-website

That's a nice way to explain this licenses in a understandable way :D